# ¿Existe algún formato canónico para representar resultados de enfrentamientos deportivos?

Tags: puntuación, deportes

Cada vez que leo resultados deportivos veo un formato diferente:

- Barcelona 5 - 0 Real Madrid
- Barcelona 5 : 0 Real Madrid
- Barcelona 5 - Real Madrid 0
- Barcelona 5 : Real Madrid 0
- Barcelona (5 : 0) Real Madrid
- etc.

(Curiosamente, el resultado siempre es el mismo, al menos el que yo deseo :D)

Busqué en el DPD y no encontré ninguna referencia sobre cómo representar estos resultados en enfrentamientos entre dos equipos en competiciones en las que hay un único resultado (en voleibol -[o *vóleibol*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=1iqOOGVeZD65Py3o1F)- o tenis el resultado es suma de sets).

¿Existe algún formato canónico recomendado o alguno especialmente desaconsejado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He encontrado una entrada en Wikilengua llamada [Ortotipografía en deportes](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Ortotipograf%C3%ADa_en_deportes). Una pequeña [sección](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Ortotipograf%C3%ADa_en_deportes#Resultados_en_encuentros) habla sobre como se escriben los resultados y dice así:

> En los encuentros de dos equipos o jugadores el resultado se da con
>   dos números separados con guion y sin espacio. Cuando corresponda, el
>   primer número corresponde al equipo local y el segundo al visitante:
>
> ```
> Ganó el partido por 1-4 [lo ganó siendo visitante]
> ```

Tus ejemplos son un poco distintos ya que está el nombre del equipo y seguido el resultado y seguramente vayan en una tabla con otros resultados. Ahí no sé si hay alguna recomendación.

Comment: No conocía este artículo de la Wikilengua. ¡Qué gran descubrimiento!

Comment: Es frecuente en Español usar el formato Local-Visitante mientras que en EEUU es más frecuente Visitante-Local. Tal vez es más "amable" nombrar primero a la visita. (incluso en varias ligas el visitante tiene derecho a usar el uniforme oscuro más bonito mientras el local usa el "blanco")